# Easiest way to plot a 3d polytope and test if a point is in it

Tags: plotting

I'd like to draw a 3D polytope from its vertices and look if a point is inside of the hull

```
    Clear["Global`*"]; t = (1 + Sqrt[5])/2;
vertices = {{0, 1, t}, {0, -1, t}, {0, 1, -t}, {0, -1, -t}, {t, 0, 1}, {t, 0, -1}, {-t, 0, 1}, {-t, 0, -1},  {1, t, 0}, {-1, t, 0}, {1, -t, 0}, {-1, -t, 0}, {1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, -1}, {1, -1, 1}, {-1, 1, 1},  {-1, -1, -1}, {-1, -1, 1}, {-1, 1, -1}, {1, -1, -1},  {0, t, 1/t}, {0, -t, 1/t}, {0, t, -1/t}, {0, -t, -1/t}, {1/t, 0, t}, {1/t, 0, -t}, {-1/t, 0, t}, {-1/t, 0, -t}, {t, 1/t, 0}, {-t, 1/t, 0}, {t, -1/t, 0}, {-t, -1/t, 0} }
```

Looking at the in-built help I tried this function with no results

```
Omega = ConvexHullMesh[vertices];
Show[HighlightMesh[%, Style[2, Opacity[0.5]]],Graphics3D[Point[Omega]]]
```

and then I tried the function

```
test[z_] = RegionMember[Omega, z];
```

Do you know how can I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
t = (1 + Sqrt[5])/2;
vertices = {{0, 1, t}, {0, -1, t}, {0, 1, -t}, {0, -1, -t}, {t, 0, 
    1}, {t, 0, -1}, {-t, 0, 1}, {-t, 0, -1}, {1, t, 0}, {-1, t, 
    0}, {1, -t, 0}, {-1, -t, 0}, {1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, -1}, {1, -1, 
    1}, {-1, 1, 1}, {-1, -1, -1}, {-1, -1, 1}, {-1, 
    1, -1}, {1, -1, -1}, {0, t, 1/t}, {0, -t, 1/t}, {0, 
    t, -1/t}, {0, -t, -1/t}, {1/t, 0, t}, {1/t, 0, -t}, {-1/t, 0, 
    t}, {-1/t, 0, -t}, {t, 1/t, 0}, {-t, 1/t, 0}, {t, -1/t, 
    0}, {-t, -1/t, 0}};
Omega = ConvexHullMesh[vertices];
HighlightMesh[Omega, {Style[2, Opacity[0.5]], Style[0, Red]}]
```

```
test = RegionMember[Omega];
SeedRandom[123];
pts = RandomPoint[Cube[4], 20];
test /@ pts

Graphics3D[{{If[test@#, Directive[AbsolutePointSize[10], Red], 
      Directive[AbsolutePointSize[5], Blue]], Point@#} & /@ 
   pts, {Yellow, Opacity[.9], Omega}}, Boxed -> False]
```

[image]